# How can I insert a certain range of years and its months in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, visual-studio-code, sql-insert

I need to insert a specific range of years and months into a table so I can relate some climate data to those dates. Just like the table bellow:

| year | month |
| --- | --- |
| 1961 | 1 |
| 1961 | 2 |
| 1961 | 3 |
| 1961 | ... |
| 1961 | 12 |
| ... | ... |
| 2019 | 12 |

I am a beginner to SQL so i'm having a hard time coding this. I'm using VSC connected to a PostgresSQL Server. Can anyone help me?

I tried searching for a sollution here in stackoverflow but couldn't find it.

Comment: It would make sense to describe how you're planning to use these. Also, if you only generate years and months, you're still the day field short of them being actual *dates*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html)() and [extract](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)():

```
INSERT INTO your_table(year, month)
SELECT extract(year from d) as year
    ,   extract(month from d) as month
FROM generate_series('1950-01-01'::timestamp -- start date
         , '2049-12-01' -- end date
         , interval '1 month') g(d);
```

Just set your start and end date (the timestamp) correct and generate_series() creates the entire list. Extract() gives you the year and the month.

Answer (score 0):

```
`with yearmonths as ( select EXTRACT('year' FROM gen) _year , EXTRACT('month' FROM gen) _month from 
 generate_series ('1961-01-01'::date,current_date,'1 month'::interval) gen
)
-- insert into ...
select _year, _month from yearmonths`
```

it's probably easier for beginner to use months like using CTE (the with part) than using generate_series directly

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT year, generate_series(1,12) AS "month" 
FROM generate_series(1961,2019) AS "year";
```

*Numbers* of years and months you showed can be [generated](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) directly, without having to [extract](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) them from [`date`/`timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html): [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/4JOzcB04).

If you showed how you plan to use these, it might turn out to be more helpful to generate actual `date`-type dates, not numbers representing them.

Comment: [`Generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) gives out numbers directly, by default. You *can* ask it to instead generate `date` and then call `date_part()` or `extract()` on it to get the number, but that's [just inefficient](https://dbfiddle.uk/EoFAwOqk).

Comment: It might be "inefficient" to use extract(), but as long as the weather in the year 100000 is unknown, it doesn't matter how many extra microseconds it takes to create a few hundred records once. On my laptop it takes 0.860 milliseconds

Comment: @FrankHeikens The 2e5 sample/range size is there to amplify the difference, not to suggest it's a reasonable use case. If you mean to say it doesn't matter if it runs [.2ms or .5ms](https://dbfiddle.uk/nkIq3siY) - this wasn't an attempt to disagree on that. My main point is if they want numbers, they can get them directly without jumping in and out of `date` - saved code, time and memory are negligible, but they won't hurt either. At the same time I underlined that depending on how they plan to use it, they might actually want to generate `date` *and keep it*, without turning it into a number.